# How to generate a identifier for set of rows using SQL?

Tags: python, sql, data-manipulation, amazon-athena

I have a table that stores stream data from the website. Within this, all records that start and end with a particular set of combinations of columns are considered a session. However, it is not flagged at all.[image]

In this attached picture, I'm trying to generate the "New Column". So basically if the row has Click, Landing Page, Main Page that's the start of a session and if the row has Time Out, Landing Page that's the end of the session.

Is it possible to generate this in SQL? Any ideas or pointers are much appreciated. Thanks!!

Edit: I'm not having much luck with SQL. My last resort is to attempt with Python. Any experts in Python to help?

Comment: What is the column which tracks the user?

Comment: I don’t have that column

Comment: What if row with _"Time Out, Landing Page"_ never happens before next _"Click, Landing Page, Main Page"_? What if there are actions recorded after timeout but before next session?

Comment: They do.. But it's very rare and the business doesn't mind losing those sessions. But the main concentration is to identify what happens within the session. So it's fine with such outliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisrt, because you don't have a user ID for the events in your table, you can't determine which "session" a particular event belongs to, except by tracking the start of the "session" when the "Click - Landing Page - Main Page" event occurs.

Second, according to your answer to the question

> What if row with "Time Out, Landing Page" never happens before next "Click, Landing Page, Main Page"? What if there are actions recorded after timeout but before next session?

> They do.. But it's very rare and the business doesn't mind losing those sessions. But the main concentration is to identify what happens within the session. So it's fine with such outliers

tracing the occurrence of the "Landing Page - Timeout" event to detect the end of the session does not make sense (since it can be written after the start of a new session or not written at all).

From these two points you can determine the beginning of the session, and its end is the beginning of a new one, and all events belongs to the current session until it ends with the beginning of a new one.

If all of the above is correct, you can use a simple query like this

```
SELECT 
    'Session ' || 
    SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Click' AND currentpage = 'Landing Page' AND destinationpage = 'Main Page' THEN 1
        END) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS sessionid,
    *
FROM events
```

The idea is to sum the values, which are set to `1` if the start of a new session is found. Then all events within the session will have the same sum value.

Query output

| sessionid | timestamp | event | currentpage | destinationpage | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:07 | Click | Landing Page | Main Page |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:07 | Redirect | Main Page | Videos |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:09 | Click | Videos |  | Video 1 Playing |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:09 | Click | Videos |  | Video 2 Playing |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:30 | Click | Videos | Content |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:36 | Random System Msg | Content |  |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:36 | Random System Msg | Content |  |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:08:37 | Click | Content | Page 5 |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:09:56 | Random System Msg | Page 5 |  |  |
| Session 1 | 2022-03-08 14:09:57 | Time Out | Page 5 | Landing Page |  |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-08 15:28:02 | Click | Landing Page | Main Page |  |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-08 15:28:02 | Redirect | Main Page | Videos |  |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-08 15:28:02 | Click | Videos |  | Video 1 Playing |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-08 15:28:02 | Click | Videos |  | Video 2 Playing |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-08 15:28:02 | Time Out | Page 5 | Landing Page |  |

I used PostgreSQL and the `SUM()` aggregation function with the `OVER()` window function to demonstrate my approach, but Amazon-Athena [should support it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_SUM.html).

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3a2627885a0da4ff91ac8d1d4e651462)

Comment: Your method is working like charm for most of my records. I do have one hiccup though. I now have an additional condition that says, "WHEN event = 'Click' AND currentpage = 'Landing Page' AND destinationpage = 'Main Page' AND details = 'Random Stuff'" can also be the start of a session. I tried adding that condition and it works with PostgreSQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=755aa40fbf7a662da148a141114362b1 But when I try this in Athena the sessions are breaking out to 2 and 3 from the record where the details has 'Random Stuff'. Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have any id or primary key in the table to use row sorting by it and not by `timestamp` values ​​as there can be multiple events with the same `timestamp` value (this is the cause of the issue)?

Comment: If you do, you can use a it in the `OVER (ORDER BY id)`  function, like this
`SELECT 
    'Session ' || 
    SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Click' 
                  AND currentpage = 'Landing Page' 
                  AND destinationpage = 'Main Page' 
                  AND details IN ('', 'Random Stuff')
             THEN 1
        END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS sessionid,
    *
FROM events`

Comment: If you don't, then you can generate it using the `ROW_NUMBER` function in subquery like this `SELECT 
    'Session ' || 
    SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'Click' 
                  AND currentpage = 'Landing Page' 
                  AND destinationpage = 'Main Page' 
                  AND details IN ('', 'Random Stuff')
             THEN 1
        END) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS sessionid,
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
    FROM events
) events `

Comment: You can check the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a48377880667c75ceb2fd5967bc4b571

Answer (score 1):

Let me give it a try. I'll explain what I've done in each step, so this answer will be longer but hopefully easier to follow. Warning: I don't know anything about Amazon Athena, so I'm using MySQL syntax, but it shouldn't be that different.

Some preparation for those who want to try it on their own (using MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE log_entries (
  TimeStamp       datetime    NOT NULL,
  Event           varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  CurrentPage     varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  DestinationPage varchar(30),
  Details         varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO log_entries VALUES
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:07', 'Click',             'Landing Page', 'Main Page',    NULL),
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:07', 'Redirect',          'Main Page',    'Videos',       NULL),
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:09', 'Click',             'Videos',       NULL,           'Video 1 Playing'),
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:09', 'Click',             'Videos',       NULL,           'Video 2 Playing'),
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:36', 'Random System Msg', 'Content',      NULL,           NULL),
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:36', 'Random System Msg', 'Content',      NULL,           NULL),
  ('2022-08-03 14:08:36', 'Click',             'Content',      'Page 5',       NULL),
  ('2022-08-03 14:09:56', 'Random System Msg', 'Page 5',       NULL,           NULL),
  ('2022-08-03 14:09:57', 'Time Out',          'Page 5',       'Landing Page', NULL),
  ('2022-09-03 15:28:02', 'Click',             'Landing Page', 'Main Page',    NULL),
  ('2022-09-03 15:28:02', 'Redirect',          'Main Page',    'Videos',       NULL),
  ('2022-09-03 15:28:02', 'Click',             'Videos',       NULL,           'Video 1 Playing'),
  ('2022-09-03 15:28:02', 'Click',             'Videos',       NULL,           'Video 2 Playing'),
  ('2022-09-03 15:28:02', 'Time Out',          'Page 5',       'Landing Page', NULL);
```

First, we'll need session starts and ends:

```
SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Click' AND CurrentPage='Landing Page'
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Time Out' AND DestinationPage='Landing Page'
```

| TimeStamp | Event | CurrentPage | DestinationPage | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-03 14:08:07 | Click | Landing Page | Main Page | NULL |
| 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Landing Page | Main Page | NULL |
| 2022-08-03 14:09:57 | Time Out | Page 5 | Landing Page | NULL |
| 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Time Out | Page 5 | Landing Page | NULL |

We want to have ranges, so that we know from a single row when a session starts and when it ends.
That is, we want to order by TimeStamp and 'pull up' values of the next row to the current row:

```
WITH session_events AS (
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Click' AND CurrentPage='Landing Page'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Time Out' AND DestinationPage='Landing Page'
)
SELECT TimeStamp              AS SessionStart, 
       lead(TimeStamp) OVER w AS SessionEnd,
       Event                  AS StartEvent,
       lead(Event)     OVER w AS EndEvent,
       CurrentPage,
       DestinationPage
  FROM session_events
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY TimeStamp);
```

Which results in:

| SessionStart | SessionEnd | StartEvent | EndEvent | CurrentPage | DestinationPage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-03 14:08:07 | 2022-08-03 14:09:57 | Click | Time Out | Landing Page | Main Page |
| 2022-08-03 14:09:57 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Time Out | Click | Page 5 | Landing Page |
| 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Time Out | Landing Page | Main Page |
| 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | NULL | Time Out | NULL | Page 5 | Landing Page |

This are not yet just sessions. A session is given by a row with appropriate start and end events:

```
WITH session_events AS (
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Click' AND CurrentPage='Landing Page'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Time Out' AND DestinationPage='Landing Page'
), session_ranges AS (
  SELECT TimeStamp              AS SessionStart, 
         lead(TimeStamp) OVER w AS SessionEnd,
         Event                  AS StartEvent,
         lead(Event)     OVER w AS EndEvent,
         CurrentPage,
         DestinationPage
    FROM session_events
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY TimeStamp)
)
SELECT * FROM session_ranges
 WHERE StartEvent = 'Click' and EndEvent = 'Time Out';
```

| SessionStart | SessionEnd | StartEvent | EndEvent | CurrentPage | DestinationPage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-03 14:08:07 | 2022-08-03 14:09:57 | Click | Time Out | Landing Page | Main Page |
| 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Time Out | Landing Page | Main Page |

Next, we can give those session names. We'll do this by concatenating some name with the number of the current row:

```
WITH session_events AS (
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Click' AND CurrentPage='Landing Page'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Time Out' AND DestinationPage='Landing Page'
), session_ranges AS (
  SELECT TimeStamp              AS SessionStart, 
         lead(TimeStamp) OVER w AS SessionEnd,
         Event                  AS StartEvent,
         lead(Event)     OVER w AS EndEvent,
         CurrentPage,
         DestinationPage
    FROM session_events
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY TimeStamp)
), unnamed_sessions AS (
  SELECT * FROM session_ranges
   WHERE StartEvent = 'Click' and EndEvent = 'Time Out'
) 
SELECT CONCAT('Session ', row_number() over ()) AS session_name,
       s.*
  FROM unnamed_sessions s;
```

| session_name | SessionStart | SessionEnd | StartEvent | EndEvent | CurrentPage | DestinationPage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:07 | 2022-08-03 14:09:57 | Click | Time Out | Landing Page | Main Page |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Time Out | Landing Page | Main Page |

As we've now names for the sessions, we can map them to the original data:

```
WITH session_events AS (
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Click' AND CurrentPage='Landing Page'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM log_entries WHERE Event='Time Out' AND DestinationPage='Landing Page'
), session_ranges AS (
  SELECT TimeStamp              AS SessionStart, 
         lead(TimeStamp) OVER w AS SessionEnd,
         Event                  AS StartEvent,
         lead(Event)     OVER w AS EndEvent,
         CurrentPage,
         DestinationPage
    FROM session_events
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY TimeStamp)
), unnamed_sessions AS (
  SELECT * FROM session_ranges
   WHERE StartEvent = 'Click' and EndEvent = 'Time Out'
), sessions AS ( 
  SELECT CONCAT('Session ', row_number() over ()) AS session_name,
         s.*
    FROM unnamed_sessions s
)
SELECT sessions.session_name,
       log_entries.*
  FROM log_entries 
  LEFT JOIN sessions ON log_entries.TimeStamp BETWEEN sessions.SessionStart and sessions.SessionEnd;
```

This query finally leads to the desired result:

| session_name | TimeStamp | Event | CurrentPage | DestinationPage | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:07 | Click | Landing Page | Main Page | NULL |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:07 | Redirect | Main Page | Videos | NULL |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:09 | Click | Videos | NULL | Video 1 Playing |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:09 | Click | Videos | NULL | Video 2 Playing |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:36 | Random System Msg | Content | NULL | NULL |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:36 | Random System Msg | Content | NULL | NULL |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:08:36 | Click | Content | Page 5 | NULL |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:09:56 | Random System Msg | Page 5 | NULL | NULL |
| Session 1 | 2022-08-03 14:09:57 | Time Out | Page 5 | Landing Page | NULL |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Landing Page | Main Page | NULL |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Redirect | Main Page | Videos | NULL |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Videos | NULL | Video 1 Playing |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Click | Videos | NULL | Video 2 Playing |
| Session 2 | 2022-09-03 15:28:02 | Time Out | Page 5 | Landing Page | NULL |

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
with s_start as
(
  Select 'Session' || row_number() over (order by timestamp) s,
  timestamp st
  from table_name
  where event='Click' and CurrentPage='Landing Page' and DestinationPage='Main Page'
),
s_end as
(
  Select 'Session' || row_number() over (order by timestamp) s,
  timestamp en
  from table_name
  where event='Time Out' and DestinationPage='Landing Page'
)
select A.s, C.timeStamp, C.event, C.currentpage, C.destinationpage, C.details
from s_start A
join s_end B
on A.s =B.s
join table_name C
on C.timestamp >= A.st and C.timestamp <=B.en
order by C.timestamp
```

The CTE `s_start`: to select all sessions start date with sessions names.

The CTE `s_end`: to select all sessions end date with sessions names.

Where, session names assigned according to the order of start/ end date for each session. (Supposing that each session has start/ end dates)

At the end, join this two CTEs with the base table to assign sessions to timestamps.

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bce17597145602d1bd624391f74030d6). (the demo is on Postgres SQL)